# Replace double quotes in json string with empty string

Tags: c#, regex, string, json, replace

I have problem with deserialization of json string, because string is bad format.

For example json object consist string property  statusMessage with value "Hello **"dog"** ".

The correct format should be  "Hello **\" dog \"**   " .

I would like remove double quotes from this property.

Something Like this. "Hello **"dog"** ".  -> "Hello  dog ".

Here is it original json string which I work.

```
"{\"jancl\":{\"idUser\":18438201,\"nick\":\"JANCl\",\"photo\":\"1\",\"sex\":1,\"photoAlbums\":1,\"videoAlbums\":0,\"sefNick\":\"jancl\",\"profilPercent\":75,\"emphasis\":false,\"age\":\"-\",\"isBlocked\":false,\"PHOTO\":{\"normal\":\"http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1843/82/n_18438201.jpg?v=1\",\"medium\":\"http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1843/82/m_18438201.jpg?v=1\",\"24x24\":\"http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1843/82/s_18438201.jpg?v=1\"},\"PLUS\":{\"active\":false,\"activeTo\":\"0000-00-00\"},\"LOCATION\":{\"idRegion\":\"6\",\"regionName\":\"Trenčiansky kraj\",\"idCity\":\"138\",\"cityName\":\"Trenčianske Teplice\"},\"STATUS\":{\"isLoged\":true,\"isChating\":false,\"idChat\":0,\"roomName\":\"\",\"lastLogin\":1294925369},\"PROJECT_STATUS\":{\"photoAlbums\":1,\"photoAlbumsFavs\":0,\"videoAlbums\":0,\"videoAlbumsFavs\":0,\"videoAlbumsExts\":0,\"blogPosts\":0,\"emailNew\":0,\"postaNew\":0,\"clubInvitations\":0,\"dashboardItems\":1},\"STATUS_MESSAGE\":{\"statusMessage\":\"\"Status\"\",\"addTime\":\"1294872330\"},\"isFriend\":false,\"isIamFriend\":false}}"
```

Problem is here, json string consist this object:

```
"STATUS_MESSAGE": {"statusMessage":" "some "bad" value"   ", "addTime" :"1294872330"}
```

Condition of string which I want modified:

- string start with    **"statusMessage":"**
- string can has any   **lenght from 0 -N **
- string end with      **", "addTime**

So I try write pattern for string which start with "statusMessage":", has any lenght and is ended with ", "addTime.

Here is it:

```
 const string pattern = "  \" statusMessage \" : \"  .*?  \",\"addTime\"  ";

 var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

//here i would replace " with empty string
 string result = regex.Replace(jsonString, match => ???);
```

But I think pattern is wrong, also I don’t know how replace double quotes with empty string (remove double quotes).

My goal is :

```
"statusMessage":" "some "bad" value"
```

to   `"statusMessage":" "some bad value"`

Thank for advice

Comment: I assume there's absolutely no chance of fixing the data source itself? I usually find that by the time a machine-generated string is shown to be in a bad format, I don't trust the source not to mess up things I haven't seen. This is particularly true of XML - a data source which serves malformed XML is usually not taking the sane approach of using an XML API, which makes me wonder where else their sanity is lacking. I would view JSON in the same way.

Comment: If the strings can contain colons and commas  (`:`, `,`), which is very likely, I don't think the problem is solvable - you can miss whole keys and values, or create excess ones.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I haven’t any chance to correct json format on server, I think use regExp is only the one solution. Because I need deserialize this json to CLR object, so firts must be json string in correct format. I am not friendly with regex, json scope. If you can help me I would be glad.

Comment: @Kobi. I would like hear solution no that is not possible ;)

Comment: Here's an example: this is a legal JSON property, with a single key: `key:"val1\",notkey:\"val2\",dummy:"`. You see `key:"val1",notkey:"val2",dummy:"` - how can you tell it was a single value? (I may be able to find a simpler example, but you get the point)

Comment: to Kobi: STATUS_MESSAGE can consit only  properties, statusMessage and addTime. I think my solution is possible, but I have problem with regExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var str = '"STATUS_MESSAGE": {"statusMessage":" "some "bad" value"   ", "addTime" :"1294872330"}"';
str = str.replace(/("statusMessage"\s*:\s*")(.+?)("\s*,\s*"addTime)/, function(m0,m1,m2,m3) { return m1 + m2.replace(/"/g,'') + m3; });

//now str == "STATUS_MESSAGE": {"statusMessage":" some bad value   ", "addTime" :"1294872330"}"
```

Edit: sorry i don't know why i confused this with a javascript question :s - You are able to do a very similar approach in c# tho i can't come up with the syntax right now.

Answer (score 2):

To serialize json on client side I use something like this:

```
    var JSON = JSON || {};  

    JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {
        var t = typeof (obj);
        if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
            // simple data type  
            if (t == "string") obj = '"' + obj + '"';
            return String(obj);
        }
        else {
            // recurse array or object  
            var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
            for (n in obj) {
                v = obj[n]; t = typeof (v);
                if (t == "string") v = '"' + v + '"';
                else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = JSON.stringify(v);
                json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
            }
            return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
        }
    };
```

then

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({
        someThing1: [
            { Id: '001', FooValue: ''},
            { Id: '002', FooValue: ''}
        ],
        someThing2: [
            { Id: '001', FooValue: ''},
            { Id: '002', FooValue: ''}
        ]
    }),
    ...
});
```

On server-side I use Newton.Json ( http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx )

```
object deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestParameterTextRepresentation, RootType);
```

If you have no ability to modify client-side script to pass correct json-string, then all your regexps are vain effort.

Answer (score 1):

While it is an extremely weak, hacky, solution, this should work in simple cases:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=""statusMessage"":"").*?(?="",""addTime"")";
string result = Regex.Replace(malformedJSON, pattern,
                              match => match.Value.Replace("\"", ""));
```

I'm using lookarounds to find the string, and then remove all quotes from it. You may also escape them by replacing with `"\\\""`.

Comment: @user572844 - So, if I may ask - How did you end up with the JavaScript solution?

Comment: Hi kobi, I omited js solution. Because I have web service wich call another service and get invalid json, on this service I repair this json string a add new data and this correct json I send on ajax req. Thank for your question and help. My solution is temporary solution but now I have another problem with higher priority. Sory, that I answer later I have much of work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This (Not a perfect solution though):

```
            string data = "\"STATUS_MESSAGE\": {\"statusMessage\":\" \"some \"bad\" value\"   \", \"addTime\" :\"1294872330\"}";

        Regex rxStatusMessage = new Regex("\\s*\"statusMessage\"\\s*:\"\\s*");
        Regex rxAddTime = new Regex("\",\\s*\"addTime\"\\s*:");

        data = rxStatusMessage.Replace(data, "\x02");
        data = rxAddTime.Replace(data, "\x03");

        Regex rxReplace = new Regex("\x02.*\x03");

        data = rxReplace.Replace(data, m => m.Value.Replace("\"", ""));

        data = data.Replace("\x02", "\"statusMessage\":\"");
        data = data.Replace("\x03", "\", \"addTime\" :");
```